# Unable to find a valid DotNetBrowser Licence. Please make sure you have set up your licence correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnetbrowser

Recently i buy the license of DotNetBrowser, but when i substitute the file teamdev.licenses of my proyect the form give me an error when run the application:   Unable to find a valid DotNetBrowser Licence. Please make sure you have set up your licence correctly. and the browser never open, i alredy changed the build action to Embedded resourse.

Answer (score -1):

At first, try to clean and rebuild your project. Also, check if the previous licence was completely removed from your project.

If that does not help, feel free to contact DotNetBrowser Support.